# Hibernate + JPA Criteria API not setting parameters in Many-To-Many relationship query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I have a Many-To-Many relationship between Schedule and Agent (via the property assignedAgents).

I want to find Schedules that contain ANY of the agents I supply. I am trying to do this:

```
List<Agent> agentsToMatch = // ... I want schedules with any of these agents

CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Schedule> query = cb.createQuery(Schedule.class);
Root<Schedule> schedule = query.from(Schedule.class);
query.where(schedule.get(Schedule_.assignedAgents).in( agentsToMatch ));
```

Using Hibernate 5.2.7, I get the following query when supplying 2 agents in the array:

```
select generatedAlias0 from Schedule as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.assignedAgents in (:param0, :param1)
```

However, the parameters seem not be set, as I get the following exception:

```
WARN [qtp1782580546-44] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:129 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22023
ERROR [qtp1782580546-44] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:131 - No value specified for parameter 1.
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not extract ResultSet
  at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
  at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
  at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1419)
  at org.hibernate.Query.getResultList(Query.java:427)
  at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:72)
```

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by replacing .get with .join:
Before:

```
query.where(schedule.get(Schedule_.assignedAgents).in( agentsToMatch ));
```

After:

```
query.where(schedule.join(Schedule_.assignedAgents).in( agentsToMatch ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way should be

```
query.where(schedule.get(Schedule_.assignedAgents)
.in(cb.parameter(List.class, "agentsToMatch" );
```

Then you supply parameter to your query

```
query.setParameter("agentsToMatch", agentsToMatch);
```

Comment: Thanks, but somehow I stil have the same problem: I am using the .setParameter on the Query<Schedule> I get on session.createQuery(query);  But hibernate does not seem to set the value: "No value specified for parameter 1."

Comment: Post your complete query, please

Comment: CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
  
CriteriaQuery<Schedule> query = cb.createQuery(Schedule.class);
  
Root<Schedule> schedule = query.from(Schedule.class);
  
query.where(schedule.get(Schedule_.assignedAgents).in(cb.parameter(List.class, "agentsToMatch")));
query.distinct(true);
  
Query<Schedule> q = session.createQuery(query);

q.setParameter("agentsToMatch", this.agentsToMatch);

System.out.println(q.getResultList());

Comment: I also tried using setParameterList(), as I would have done in standard HQL, but I get a very bizarre exception: Named parameter [agentsToMatch] type mismatch; Date was passed, but parameter defined as [List]

Comment: Please post your Schedule class (update your question). Why do you refer to Schedule_ with underscore. Are you using static metamodel?